# Generate Data where outcome is conditional on independent variables

Tags: normal-distribution, python, conditional-expectation

I want to generate a synthetic dataset {Y, X1, X2}. Independent random variables X1 and X2 follow bernouli distribution where probabilities for X1 and X2 are known.

Whereas, outcome variable Y needs to follow normal distribution with an expected mean E(Y|X1,X2) = X1 + 3.2X2 and Standard Deviation of 1.4.

n = 1000
X1 = np.random.binomial(1,.25,n)
X2 = np.random.binomial(1,.30,n)

Not sure, how to generate Y which is conditional on X1 and X2, normally distributed and follows the formula for each of the observation

Please help.

Comment: This appears to be a request for Python code with no embedded statistical query. As such it's off-topic here. Please read advice on software-related questions in the Help Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, consider the model**: 
$$Y = X_1 + \beta X_2 + \nu$$
where, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are binomial random variate, and $\nu \sim N(0, 1.4^2)$. Now, you can see, 
$$E(Y|X_1, X_2) = X_1 + \beta X_2$$
$$V(Y|X_1, X_2) =  Var(\nu) = 1.4^2$$

Since, $\nu$ follows normal distribution, therefore, 
$$Y|X_1, X_2 \sim N(X_1 + \beta X_2, 1.4^2)$$

**Steps to Generate Y**

1. Generate $X_1$, $X_2$ and $\nu$ from the given distribution.
2. Generate $Y$ using $Y = X_1 + \beta X_2 + \nu$.

**R Code**

```
X1 = rbinom(1000,1, .25)
X2 = rbinom(1000, 1, .30)
Y = X1 + X2*3.2 + rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 1.4)
plot(density(Y))
```

[image: Density Plot of Y]

Comment: Thanks Neeraj, Will the analysis be same if I add additional condition of X2 is functionally dependent on X1, and Y is conditionally dependent on X1 and X2 ?

Comment: Yes, Just generate your number accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is R code, not python code:

```
    n = 1000
    X1 = rbinom(n,1,.25)
    X2 = rbinom(n,1,.30)
    y = rnorm(n=1000,mean = X1+3.2*X2,sd=1.4)
```